# What caused the volume bar to be gone?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, audio, sound-card

I don't know what has happened, but suddenly my laptop can't play any sound and the volume bar has gone.

It's an Acer Aspire 4937 G, running Windows Vista Home Premium.

**Update:**
Restarting my laptop has fixed the problem (for now).

But I would like to know what caused this to happen in the first place, so that if it happens again I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen that the playback device is disabled in the list of devices.

May be you had a piece of software that did that.

Comment: i don't think any software i had did that.. anyway i was thinking may it be because my laptop had a slight hit on the door?

Comment: @Pacerier Uhm, no, I don't think that's possible. Maybe the audio driver stopped working because of some bug, who knows?

Comment: @slhck you mean a bug in a software i have or a windows bug?

Comment: @Pacerier Either way - if you can't reproduce it I wouldn't worry all too much about it.